# How to process If.. else based on the ID value, where ID is may accessable and sometimes not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to access a cell value which will have data later. `generator_cell` is the `<td>` value.

I am trying to export the HTML table to excel format whether the cell value loaded with its value.

I tried this piece of code but it not working.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    if (document.getElementById("generator_cell").innerHTML() != '') {
        $("#generator").table2excel({
            exclude: ".generator",
            name: "Worksheet Name",
            filename: "Generator Report" 
          });
    }else {
        alert('no data');
        }
    });
```

I tried the following too.

```
if(document.getElementById("generator_cell").innerHTML() === null)

if($('#generator_cell').html() != '')

if($('#generator_cell').innerhtml() != '')
```

The table will gets its value later on a ajax call. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: innerHTML() nede to be just innerHTML

Comment: I tried but it not worked. :(

Comment: First make check like if(typeof document.getElementById("generator_cell") != 'undefined' )  then use like this : innerHTML == ""

Comment: I tried both but it not worked

Answer (score 0):

How about just a simple val check with jQuery?

```
$("button").click(function(){
  if ( !($('#generator_cell').val()) {
      $("#generator").table2excel({
          exclude: ".generator",
          name: "Worksheet Name",
          filename: "Generator Report" 
      });
   } else {
      alert('no data');
   }
 });
```

I'm not sure about the table2excel stuff - haven't worked with it yet.